# Ubuntu 18.04: Two wireless interfaces

Tags: networking, network-manager, 18.04

I just install Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop.

The laptop already has a wireless interface, when i try to plug in a USB wireless interface and try to turnoff one of them the other will stop too.

And i can't create a Hotspot on the USB interface, the only option i can find on the Settings > Wi-Fi and it show me the two interfaces on top when select the USB interface and i click the options i find the Turn on Hotspot and this option will only create Hotspot on the build-in interface.

Any info will be helpful,
if there a way to create hotspot from command line please write it down.

#### __

## Update

To make the question clear, if you have two WiFi interfaces (wlo1, wlx##_usb)

[View from the WiFi Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6QLg.jpg)

#### First Problem:

if you try to turnoff one of them from the Wifi Settings it will turnoff the other even from the top drop list.

[GIF show the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJ2cA.gif)

#### [Solved] Second Problem:

When I try to create a Hotspot for the (wlx##_usb) from the Wifi Settings it will select the (wlo1) as the interface for the Hotspot even if i'm on the  (wlx##_usb) interface!

[Option to create the hotspot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8lNP.jpg)

**Solution:** For this problem i can use the command `nm-connection-editor` and it show me the old connections list and i can edit what ever i want, but if I stop the connection from the Settings you can't select it back!

Comment: Linux Mint 20 in 2021 - this issue with Network Manager still there.

Answer (score 0):

Type in ifconfig if you're using gnome network manager to view your 2nd interface which may be wlan1 or something similar to lpqrso0, if you're not using gnome network manager use ip

Then in the Network Manager file you want to have the wireless adapter as a hot plug

It may also help if you had dhcp set up so your system could determine what is set up.

You're question is kind of vague, can you please upload your journalctl or a similar Auth log, followed by the commands you were given to take down these interfaces

Answer (score 0):

**2nd Problem Solution:** For this problem i can use the command `nm-connection-editor` and it show me the old connections list and i can edit what ever i want, **but** if I stop the connection from the Settings you can't select it back!

Answer (score -1):

You can try Linux WiFi Hotspot. It is able to create a hotspot using the same wifi card which is connected to an AP already (similar to Windows 10).

You can check it out [here on GitHub](https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot).